# react native fbsdk MODULE_NOT_FOUND after link commend

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I searched for this error on the git repo and online but I didn't find anything what brings me to here. React native is totally new for me so if I missed something stupid, my apologize.

I'm trying to install & link react-native-fbsdk in my react-native project: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk

I went through these steps:

```
react-native init [YourApp]
```

Result: done, project created

```
react-native install react-native-fbsdk
```

Output: *Scanning 712 folders for symlinks in C:\wamp\www\chatapp\node_modules (26ms)
rnpm-install info Module react-native-fbsdk has been successfully installed & linked*

```
react-native link react-native-fbsdk
```

Output: *Scanning 712 folders for symlinks in C:\wamp\www\chatapp\node_modules (29ms)
{ [Error: Cannot find module 'C:\wamp\www\chatapp\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\package.json'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }*

Print screen:
[image: error output]

Of course when I try to build my app with react-native run-android I got this:

```
...
:app:processDebugResources                 
:app:generateDebugSources                 
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE      
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac                 
C:\wamp\www\chatapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\chatapp\MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
...
```

**More Info:**

- React native version: 0.42.3
- npm -version 4.2.0
- I didn't find "react-native-fbsdk" folder under
  my node_modules folder.
- Windows 8.1
- I'm working with Android Studio
- Android SDK Platform-Tools 25.0.4
- Android SDK Tools 25.2.3

Thank you in advance.
Leo.

**EDIT + UPDATE:** Added react-native tag. Facebook team investigated this and it looks like an issue with React Native itself.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1889723254644374

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After few days with the community I found the problem!

This line is not valid commend for react native!

```
react-native install react-native-fbsdk
```

Instead we need to write:

```
npm i -S react-native-fbsdk
```

and then

```
react-native link react-native-fbsdk
```

Comment: yep... react-native install react-native-fbsdk command messed up the app